# ReportViewer is driving me absolutely nuts

Tags: c#, reportviewer, hyperlink

After wrestling for half a day with the Website Data Source tab, which is always showing me an empty panel, now I want to have a table cell which contains a hyperlink, but it's not working either because I didn't use a hyper link.

Because this is on development environment, I can't give it an absolute URL in the rdlc, because otherwise it won't work when I deploy it!!. So I pass in the URL from C# to the destination as a report parameter, and give Jump to URL this expression:

```
Parameters!MyAbsoluteURL + Fields!ProductId
```

But this won't work because either, and I don't know why. Can I get some help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing .Value:

```
Parameters!MyAbsoluteURL.Value + Fields!ProductId.Value
```